# Draw a Christmas tree using java

Tags: java, algorithm

**b) drawChristmasTree(int n) which takes as an input one integer value n
and then output on console a Christmas tree in which last part height equals n. The tree consists of pyramids of heights from 1 to n. The shape have to be as presented below (for
n=4):**

```
   X
   X
  XXX
   X
  XXX
 XXXXX
   X
  XXX
 XXXXX
XXXXXXX
```

I tried to do it but the output was:

```
X
  X
 XXX
   X
  XXX
 XXXXX
    X
   XXX
  XXXXX
 XXXXXXX
```

My coding:

```
public static void drawChristmassTree(int n) {
            n=1;    
            while(n<=4){
            int rowCount =1;
            for(int i = n ; i>0 ; i--) {
                for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                
                for(int j=1; j<=rowCount; j++ ) {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
                for(int j=2; j<=rowCount; j++ ) {
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
            
                System.out.println();
                rowCount++;
                
            }
            n++;
            }
        }
```

**Does anyone have any idea how to move it to the right?**

Answer (score 2):

**My approach**

In order to solve this problem, I started out writing out each case (e.g. `n=1`, `n=2`, `n=3`...) and ended up with something like this:

```
if (n < 1) {
    return;
}
if (n == 1) {
    System.out.println(" X ");
}
else if (n == 2) {
    System.out.println(" X "); // n-1 spaces
    System.out.println(" X ");
    System.out.println("XXX"); // 1, 3, 5, 7, ... n+2 pattern
}
else if (n == 3) {
    System.out.println("  X  "); // n-1 spaces
    System.out.println("  X  ");
    System.out.println(" XXX "); // 3
    System.out.println("  X  ");
    System.out.println(" XXX ");
    System.out.println("XXXXX"); // 5
}
```

Once I had a handle of the pattern, I was able to build the first function to handle drawing a single tier on the tree:

```
public static void drawTier(int currentTier, int numberOfTiers) {
    if (currentTier < 1) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < currentTier; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < numberOfTiers - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        int width = i + (i % currentTier);
        for (int k = 0; k <= width; k++) {
            System.out.print("X");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Now we can build a wrapper to build `n` number of tiers:

```
public static void drawTree(int numberOfTiers) {
    if (numberOfTiers < 1) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTiers; i++) {
        drawTier(i, numberOfTiers);
    }
}
```

and finally, we can give it a try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawTree(4);
}
```

Final output:

```
   X
   X
  XXX
   X
  XXX
 XXXXX
   X
  XXX
 XXXXX
XXXXXXX
```

Comment: oh that's a good approach! I understood how to do it now thanks!

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider accepting it as the correct answer!